# CSS Dynamically Move Div to Center of Circle

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to recreate this image in my React app:

[image]

So far this is what I have:

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './AppStyle.scss';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { testWidth: 0 };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ testWidth: (this.myInput.offsetWidth + this.mySpan.offsetWidth)*.3 });
  }

  render() {
    const { testWidth } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <span className="test" style={{top: "17px", left: testWidth}}>30%</span>
        <div className="wrapper">
          <span className="num" ref={div => {this.mySpan = div}}>5</span>
          <input ref={input => {this.myInput = input}} type="range" value="30" id="rangeInput" readOnly />
          <span className="num">15</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**App.scss**

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.test {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
}

.num {
  width: 5%;
  font-size: 150%;
  text-align: center;
}


input[type='range'] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 90%;
  height: 50px;
  background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #000000, #000000 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 60px) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #000000, #000000 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 60px) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: 90% 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

input[type='range'],
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track,
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #000000
}

input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  border: 2px solid #00B0FA;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.98);
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -23.05px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/96287/

I am unable to get my span element with class **test** to consistently find the center of the circle. As you can see, I use ref to get the width of the input and the first span. I was hoping my math in the componentDidMount would *just work* but unfortunately not. Also I realized if the user resizes the screen then the math is really off. One the one upside is that the range is disabled so don't worry about the slider moving. Also, I'm only supporting Chrome/Safari.

Comment: try removing **display:flex** for the wrapper class

Comment: @manishkumar removing it will give me a consistent spot. I added 7px and for it to always be centered. However now the numbers on the side aren't centered vertically with the range

Comment: @user2465134 Try this for span element top: 32%;left: 31.5%;                     
         <span class="test" style="top: 32%;left: 31.5%;">30%</span>

Comment: @divine that also is a fixed but only when you turn off **display: flex** which then causes problems with centering between the numbers on the ends and the range

Comment: @user2465134 try these settings for .test class ------.test {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    display: block;
    top: 32%;
    left: 31.5%;
}

Comment: @divine didn't work. I provided a fiddle for people to use/test. Using those CSS properties then refresh the screen in different size you will see it's not consistent

Comment: @user2465134 i have detailed in the answer section about what i have tested in your Jsfiddle. i think it works for me. i tried with chrome. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've forked your fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/Lzq561f8/1/

And got the right equation that'll fit with all values

```
testWidth: (this.myInput.offsetWidth * 0.3) - (50 * 0.3)
(input width * Value) - ( slider-thumb width * value )
```

With this equation you'll get it centered with all values
The input range slider-thumb with value 0 will have same value as left :0
But at the value 100 it'll have same css value as `left : calc( 100% - it's width )`
And same proportional `left: calc( value - width/value )`

Answer (score 1):

In this answer, i will repeat what i have been mentioned in the comments section. i hope this will provide a little more clarity.

**Add below css property**

```
.test {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 32%;
  left: 31.5%;
}
```

**In your babel+JSX section, remove the style attribute for the element with class="test"**

```
<span class="test">30%</span>
```

**Below is the change i recommend you to make**
 i made these modifications and verified this in your fiddle and it works when i adjust the screen size. Let me know if you still are facing issues.

[image]

**Outputs i get while resizing the screen after introducing this fix**
[image]

> Updated

i have forked your JSfiddle into my jsfiddle account and updated the fix.
Here is my fiddle **with the fix**
 https://jsfiddle.net/Divine/48ky8yzw/2/
Let me know if it works.

Comment: Wow.. very strange. I don't get the same outcome as you do. Using a MacBook with Chrome

Comment: @user2465134 are you using the same jsfiddle? i use windows 10 with chrome

Comment: @user2465134 check my fiddle containing the answer https://jsfiddle.net/Divine/48ky8yzw/2/

Comment: Your fiddle works great. Thanks a ton for all of your help

Comment: @user2465134 this is the same answer which i mentioned in the comment section 18hours ago. :)

Comment: Yeah I know :( I'm not sure why it didn't work, I need to compare the fiddles. Thanks for sticking with me!!

Comment: this 31.5 will not work for all other values
why 1.5 plus value this equation doesn't make any sense
please check my answer with the right equation

Comment: @divine yeah I realized this will work when its at 30% but will not work if it comes in at a different percent (sorry very tired). The range will be disabled but can load at different percentages.

Comment: IE - if I change the value to 50 it will no longer be centered

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason it's not showing up in the right spot is because your math is slightly off.  You have `(this.myInput.offsetWidth + this.myDiv.offsetWidth)*.3` but I think you might want `(this.myInput.offsetWidth*.3 + this.myDiv.offsetWidth)`.  You need to add the full myDiv width to the 30% of the myInput width.

**Edit - Forgot to address the resize issue:**

I am not very familiar with react, but to get it to adjust when the window is resized, you need to listen to the resize event and recalculate the position.  Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ay1qrwok/